# Nodejs Auth0 read users with api not working (err: 400, msg: Bad HTTP authentication header format)

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, auth0

I'm trying to receive my users that are stored in Auth0. So, I tried using this website [Auth0 management API docs](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2) with my API token and API domain. This works fine! 
Then I tried to do the same in node js, but when I do that it returns an error. The error message is:

```html
"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Bad HTTP authentication header format","errorCode":"Bearer"
```

This is the code that i fount in the documentation

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://<api_url>/api/v2/users',
    headers: { authorization: 'Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    console.log(body);
});
```

The only thing that is changed is that I deleted the query string and inserted my api_url and the same access token that I used on the [Auth0 management API docs](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2) (which works). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks perfectly fine. I edited it with my hostname/access token as follows and it returned the users:

```js
var request = require("request");

var token = 'eyJ0...'

var options = { method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://tenant_name.auth0.com/api/v2/users',
    headers: { authorization: 'Bearer ' + token }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    console.log(body);
});
```

The two things that might have gone wrong in your case are:

1. You didn't properly replace the ACCESS_TOKEN in the code.
2. The access token does not have the `read:users` permission. You can verify this by pasting the token in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) and inspecting the payload.